# Wireguard Client to Server to Site VPN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, wireguard

So, i've got a little project on hand where i don't really see what I am doing wrong.

TLDR; wireguard vpn doesn't forward icmp package back to target host

I'm trying to setup a wireguard vpn as a client(s) to server to site vpn, and i've been trying to get this to work all evening long, but am kinda stuck.

I've been following the guide given here, but i just can't get it to work.
https://github.com/mjtechguy/wireguard-site-to-site

So, this here is my network setup and the path i have traced the ping package
Hosts:
docker01 - ubuntu
vpn-server - ubuntu
site client / desktop - windows

Right now i am trying to ping a pc on the site's network from the vpn server, which fails. But later other clients connected to the vpn server shall be able to communicate with the site's network.

[image: Graph of traced package]

and this is my setup regarding tracing the package
[image]

Would someone in this awesome community be so kind to have a look at this, and maybe point out what i am missing, or where i am wrong with this setup? I tried the routing commands from the github page, but had no success so far. How would the route command for this specific setup need to look?

Bonus Question: Would it be possible to not route all the traffic pointed to the www from docker01 over the vpn server? docker01 shall just access the internet, directly over the site's internet connection.

**Wireguard config on docker01**

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <****************************************>
Address = 10.200.1.4/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens18 -j MASQUERADE

PreDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp0s18 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = <****************************************>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0
Endpoint = <**********>:<***>
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

**Wireguard config on vpn-server**

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.200.1.1/24
SaveConfig = false

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE

PreDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE

ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <****************************************>

[Peer]
# Some client that shall later be able to reach 192.168.178.36 / desktop
PublicKey = <****************************************>
AllowedIPs = 10.200.1.2/32

[Peer]
# docker01
PublicKey = <****************************************>
AllowedIPs = 10.200.1.4/32, 192.168.178.0/24
```

Comment: your bonus question: `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0` is why all traffic is going through wireguard

Comment: yeah i figured that too, but here is the problem: if i use AllowedIPs = 10.200.1.0/24, 192.168.178.0/24 so that in theory only the VPN and local IPs get forwarded I am not able to access the box from the local network anymore, only from the VPN

Comment: `get forwarded` see, I think that's the issue. allowedIPs has nothing to do with *forwading*, but more to do with routing. Networking is hard

Comment: There are many screenshots all with incomplete and occluded information, but none shows clearly that the ping reached the Desktop and the ping reply came back. It's just a schematic telling it did so. I don't trust the data available in the question. If Desktop is not using WireGuard, there's no reason the container's WireGuard should have the Desktop's LAN in its AllowedIPs. Else traffic will never reach Desktop. wg-quick sets [WG's *cryptokey* routing](https://www.wireguard.com/#cryptokey-routing) + (contrary to just wg, also) standard routes.

Comment: What information are you missing in my screenshot, I'll gladly provide more info if required? Also, regarding the ping and what it reaches, in the Wireshark screenshot you can see the ICMP packet request going thru to the desktop and a reply that only reaches back to the docker01 server, I only put that in a little graph to make it easier to read

Comment: @JaromandaX I know the allowed IPs themselves do not prompt forwarding, yes... The tutorial talked about routes to configure on the docker 01 server, I tried that and couldn't really get it to work... Most I managed to do is cut off docker 01 from the local network and have it only reachable from wireguard, which is, well, absolutely not what I was trying to archive ^^

Comment: never mind your screenshot shows there's a ping reply. I'm out of ideas.